# Trying to save emails from my email account and store these in my local machine in pdf format. it gives <terminate>javaw.exe and no output is display

Tags: java

```
import java.io.; import java.util.; import javax.mail.*;

public class ReadMail {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
// String host = "pop.gmail.com"; // String user = "xyz"; // String password = "12345";

    // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    // Get a Store object that implements the specified protocol.
    Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");

    //Connect to the current host using the specified username and password.
    store.connect(host, user, password);

    //Create a Folder object corresponding to the given name.
    Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

    // Open the Folder.
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] message = folder.getMessages();

    // Display message.
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("------------ Message " + (i + 1) + " ------------");

        System.out.println("SentDate : " + message[i].getSentDate());
        System.out.println("From : " + message[i].getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("Subject : " + message[i].getSubject());
        System.out.print("Message : ");

        InputStream stream = message[i].getInputStream();
        while (stream.available() != 0) {
            System.out.print((char) stream.read());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");//trying to save the emails in local machine out.println(stream );

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    folder.close(true);
    store.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Run the java class using `java` from the command line, rather than using `javaw` (double-clicking jar file?) - `javaw` swallows all output and doesn't display exceptions.

Comment: how do i save the contained of mails in  in local machince?